# How can I implement an order bar on a wordpress site like the one Teespring uses?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

How can I use the style teespring has for the number of orders placed on a wordpress site?

Comment: How about giving us some more information (like a link or a screenshot)? If your potential answerers have to take a lot of action just to understand the question, many of them just will not bother. It is in your interest to make your question quick to understand.

Comment: Your reputation does not let you pots pictures but you can always post it on imgur and write a link.